# Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES'

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have been encountering error while starting my Spring Boot Project, Exception snippet below

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.Validation
Exception: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
```

The error occurs while trying to `@Autowired` `java.sql.Datasource` bean.

The issue is however resolved by including the Hibernate Validator dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The pom.xml snippet

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath/> 
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <querydsl.version>4.0.1</querydsl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My concern is why is necessary to include the `hibernate-validator`, if necessary why is it not been included as a transitive dependency with `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`?

**EDIT: Adding full stacktrace as requested**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.sql.DataSource com.example.DemoApplication.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework
.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration': Injection of a
utowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jd
bc.DataSourceProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.Validation
Exception: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
        at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:35)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.sql.DataSource com.example.DemoApplication.dataSource; nested exception is org.spr
ingframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration': In
jection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.auto
configure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframewo
rk.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validatio
n.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbedded
Configuration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springf
ramework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.properties; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception
is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your cl
asspath.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties org.springframe
work.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creat
ing bean with name 'spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configura
tion, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Initialization of bean failed; nested
exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI)
to your classpath.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to
 your classpath.
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:271)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$LocalValidatorFactory.run(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:441)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.getValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:375)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.determineValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:358)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:31
7)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:28
9)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        ... 55 more
```

**EDIT2: Adding `mvn dependency:tree` before `hibernate-validator`**

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.32:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.32:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- com.querydsl:querydsl-sql:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.mysema.commons:mysema-commons-lang:jar:0.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject:jar:1_2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.infradna.tool:bridge-method-annotation:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] \- com.querydsl:querydsl-sql-codegen:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO]    +- com.querydsl:querydsl-codegen:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- com.mysema.codegen:codegen:jar:0.6.6:provided
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.3.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO]    |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.9:provided
[INFO]    |     +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:provided
[INFO]    |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:provided
[INFO]    \- com.querydsl:querydsl-sql-spatial:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO]       +- com.querydsl:querydsl-spatial:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO]       |  \- org.geolatte:geolatte-geom:jar:0.13:provided
[INFO]       \- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.10:provided
```

Comment: Could you add the whole stack trace instead of a snippet. I would expect that the validator was or part of the `spring-boot-starter` (because the configuration classes have validation applied` or it to be optional. I suspect that one of the dependencies pulls in `javax.validation` which triggers the validation, which in turn needs an implementation.

Comment: edited and added full stack trace.

Comment: What also would be useful is to provide the output of `mvn dependency:tree` prior to adding the `hibernate-validator` dependency.

Comment: Looking at the output of `mvn dependency:tree` the actual culprit is `querydsl-sql` which is pulling in the `validation-api`, which in turn turns on the validation of properties. However for that to work you need an implementation. SO either include the implementation or exclude the validation api from query-dsl.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer, so I could accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[INFO] +- com.querydsl:querydsl-sql:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.mysema.commons:mysema-commons-lang:jar:0.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject:jar:1_2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.infradna.tool:bridge-method-annotation:jar:1.13:compile
```

The actual culprit is `querydsl-sql` as that is pulling in the `validation-api`. The presence of the `validation-api` in turn switches on the validation of properties.

However, as the name implies, `validation-api` is just the API, you still need an implementation to enable validation. That isn't available so you get an error. To fix you have 2 options.

1. Include the `hibernate-validator` as an dependencies (this works as you have seen)
2. Exclude the `validation-api` from the `querydsl-sql` dependency.

Either solution will work. Benefit of the first one is that Spring Boot can now detect errors in your configuration, whereas without it could not. Drawback is you have another dependency again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both *Hibernate*'s and *Spring*'s validators respectively.
if you implement `@Valid` annotation in your code you tell the VM that the validation will be firstly made by *Hibernate* and then *Spring*.

You can prevent *Hibernate* validation by unimplementing the `@Valid` annotation.